# Display a div in the timeout of a function jquery

Tags: jquery, settimeout

In my script, at some point the function 'showswords' which shows random words from an array, is "paused" or timed-out for one second. In this pause, I want to have my whitebox div appear - for exactly this one second.
I did this and it is 'okay', but I want it quicker. Is there a more clever way to accomplish this?

```
setTimeout(showswords, 1000);
$("#whitebox").fadeIn("fast").delay(1000).fadeOut("fast");
```

Comment: can u add a jsfiddle of what you have done

Comment: Quicker = change the delay?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the the speed in milliseconds of the fadein / fadeout effects. For a quicker / smoother effect try the following:

```
$("#whitebox").fadeIn(350, function(){
   $(this).delay(500).fadeOut(350);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually looking to do here? Fade in the `#whitebox` and after a moment fade out the `#whitebox` again? The `setTimeout` may be unnecessary depending on what you're trying to do. However...

If you play around with the timeout interval and the animation's duration you should be able to achieve what you want; basically `setTimeout` will allow you to defer calling a function (e.g. `showswords()`) until a certain length of time has passed (in your example 1000 ms).

When `showswords()` is executed, you can then fade in the box, `#whitebox` with a delay of however long you want, the [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) method takes an argument, `duration` with which you can define how long the animation will take, instead of passing in the duration as part of the method's options, you can specify the speed in milliseconds so the following:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#whitebox")
    .fadeIn(400)  // duration, in ms
    .promise
    .done(function(){
      $("#whitebox").fadeOut(400); // duration, in ms
    });
}), 1000);
```

... will fade in the `#whitebox` in 400 ms, and when the animation is completed it will fade it back out, in the same amount of time. This will execute approximately one-second after the timeout `setTimeout` command is executed.

Instead of using [promises](http://api.jquery.com/promise/), you can provide a second argument to the `.fadeIn()` function, and use that as the "done" callback method.